Keep tabbar when navigating to a detail page .NET MAUI
I am creating a .NET MAUI app that utilizes the AppShell as navigation service.
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="YourNamespace.AppShell">

    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent
            Title="Main Page 1"
            Icon="icon1.png"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage1}" 
            Route="nameOf(MainPage1)"/>

        <ShellContent
            Title="Main Page 2"
            Icon="icon2.png"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage2}" 
            Route="nameOf(MainPage2)"/>
    </TabBar>

    <ShellContent
            Title="Detail Page 1"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DetailPage1}" 
            Route="nameOf(DetailPage1)"/>

    <ShellContent
            Title="Detail Page 2"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DetailPage2}" 
            Route="nameOf(DetailPage2)"/>

</Shell>

With this setup when navigating to the detailpage like below removes the tabbar on the bottom when on the detail page.
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameOf(DetailPage2)}", navigationParameter);

I also tried this structure
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="YourNamespace.AppShell">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Title="Main Page 1"
            Icon="icon1.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage1}" 
            Route="nameOf(MainPage1)"/>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DetailPage1}" 
            Route="nameOf(DetailPage1)"/>
        </Tab>

        <Tab Title="Main Page 2"
            Icon="icon2.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage2}" 
            Route="nameOf(MainPage2)"/>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:DetailPage2}" 
            Route="nameOf(DetailPage2)"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>

This almost achieves what I want, but somehow this creates an extra bar at the top of my page under my title view. I can't seem to find online anyone that also runs into this problem, so I hope someone with more Maui experience can help. Thanks in advance!

What platform you are targeting? Can you help add a screenshot to your post on the extra bar?

The platform shouldn't matter since its Multi-platform App UI right.
On a more serieus note. I am targeting Android and when i can i will upload a screenshot but i think your solution might already work. Thanks for reaching out!


With this setup when navigating to the detailpage like below removes
the tabbar on the bottom when on the detail page.

You can use the code below to navigate to the DetailPage2() and it will show the bottom TabBar as expected.
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage2());


This was exactly what i was looking for thanks a lot! I do want to add to hide the back button that appears on my top bar i had to add this code:
        <BackButtonBehavior IsEnabled="False" IsVisible="False" />
</Shell.BackButtonBehavior>```

No worries, have a good day :)
